# JQuery Append Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, socket.io

I am using sockets with JQuery, In on message call of sockets I want to append a div in my html page, but as soon as the page is loaded I see an extra div already appended, How can I prevent it from appending on load of the page.

Secondly When a div is appended There is a button with id=answerit inside div on which I added onclick functionality. but when the div is appended and try to click on the answer it button it does not call the onclick function, but when the page is reloaded then it works

My code is

```
  Student.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            //alert(message.data);
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            var str = message.data;
            var ques = str.split(":");
            var questionId = ques[0];
            var questionText = ques[1];
            var question = 
                "<div class='span11' style='border:2px solid; border-radius:5px; background-color:#b0c4de;'>"+
                    "<div style='width:30px; float:left;'>" +
                        "<div class='voteup'><a id="+questionId+" vote='true' title='This answer is useful' style='cursor:pointer'>up</a></div>"+
                        "<div class='votedown'><a id="+questionId+" vote='false' title='This answer is not useful' style='cursor:pointer'>down</a></div>"+
                    "</div>"+
                    "<div style='float:left;'>"+
                        "<div style='margin-top:5px' class='span10'>"+
                            "<span>"+questionText+"</span>"+
                            "<button id="+questionId+" style='float:right' class='answerit btn'>Answer It</button>"+
                            "<button id="+questionId+" style='float:right' class='showAnswers btn'>Show Answers</button>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>";
            $('#studentsQuestions').append(question);  
            });
        };
```

HTML is

```
<div id="studentsQuestions"></div>
```

Every time I load a page I see an extra div already present with undefined text

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Java itself? Java is not the same thing as Javascript (which should have never been renamed from ECMAScript for the sake of this website).

Comment: Why do you have a `$(document).ready()` inside your `.onmessage` handler?

Comment: When I dont use it It then does not append

Comment: That's missuse of jQuery.ready. You should use that event / function to start listening to messages on socket, that way, in function that handles the message, you can be sure, that DOM is ready and operational.

Comment: If you uncomment the alert, does it fire when you load the page?

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can clean the div#studentsQuestions before appending new content

```
$("#studentsQuestion").empty().html(question);
```

Comment: also can use `$("#studentsQuestion").empty().append(question);`.

Comment: The problem will be if some valid divs are appended and someone will try to append a new div the previous ones will me removed

Comment: I think I should call it only once on page load